# Linear regression suing Scikitlearn(linear regression)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

Here is my scenarion.

```
data = [[25593.14, 39426.66],
        [98411.00, 81869.75],
        [71498.80, 62495.80],
        [38068.00, 54774.00],
        [58188.00, 43453.65],
        [10220.00, 18465.25]]
```

About data is my data model.

x-cordinates refers "Salary"
y-cordinates refers "Expenses"

I want to predict the expense when I give "Salary" i.e., X-coordinate.

Here is my sample code. Please help me out.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

data = [[25593.14, 39426.66],
        [98411.00, 81869.75],
        [71498.80, 62495.80],
        [38068.00, 54774.00],
        [58188.00, 43453.65],
        [10220.00, 18465.25]]

salary=[]
expenses=[]

for dataset in data:
    # import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    salary.append(dataset[0])
    expenses.append(dataset[1])

model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(salary, expenses)
prediction = model.predict([10200.00])
print(prediction)
```

**Error which I got:**

```
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[ 25593.14  98411.    71498.8   38068.    58188.    10220.  ].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample
```

.

Comment: and what is the problem?

Comment: Edited my question

Comment: The error tells you what to do and what the problem is (and there are probably 5 other questions here in regards to this error). I highly recommend reading sklearn's docs to see what shapes are expected. After that, read some numpy docs to not do that list-append stuff you are doing!

Comment: To add to the above, the first argument of this line:
`model.fit(salary, expenses)` is where the error is occurring, it expects a matrix of training data for the first argument, "X". [This](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html) may help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested by the comments, something like this would be a better way to work with data you want to feed into a scikit learn model. Another example can be seen [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_ols.html).

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import numpy as np

data = np.array(
        [[25593.14, 39426.66],
        [98411.00, 81869.75],
        [71498.80, 62495.80],
        [38068.00, 54774.00],
        [58188.00, 43453.65],
        [10220.00, 18465.25]]
).T

salary = data[0].reshape(-1, 1)
expenses = data[1]

model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(salary, expenses)
prediction = model.predict(np.array([10200.00]).reshape(-1, 1))
print(prediction)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

quick fix, replace this line

```
model.fit(np.array([salary]), np.array([expenses]))
```

X is expected to be an array of arrays, `array([arr1,arr2,array3,...])` same of arr1 and arr2 being arrays of at least one feature, same for y,it should be an array of containing a list of values `array[label1,label2,label3,...]`

Comment: Thanks for your help.